# What is the SuiteScript 2.0 equivalent to nlapiPrintRecord()

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Does anyone know where this method is located in 2.0. If NetSuite would put a link in the 1.0 docs for `nlapiPrintRecord()` to the 2.0 implementation, I wouldn't have to ask Stack community

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, there isn't a *direct* corollary. SuiteScript 2.0 doesn't use the same object model, so nothing returns `nlobjFile` rather some return `file.File` But that's being a bit pedantic.

All the existing options are part of [`N/render`](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4412042824.html)

The 'types' from the 1.0 `nlapiPrintRecord()` api are broken into individual methods, with the 'mode' being controlled by the enum `render.PrintMode`

There are (nearly) functional examples of each method available in the help center documentation linked to above.

Comment: You are soo helpful. Thanks alot Shea